# why can't we create our own ostream object

Tags: c++, class, object, iostream

If cout is an object of ostream class, then why can't we declare our own object, say, 'out' from the same class. i.e, isn't the following code supposed to work??

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ostream out;
    out<<"something";
}
```

or otherwise

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ostream_withassign out;
    out<<"something";
}
```

Comment: What would it do? Where would the output go?

Comment: What is `ostream_withassign` supposed to be?

Comment: why do you think it is not possible to do?

Comment: @David Schwartz The output should go to the standard output just like it does for cout

Comment: Why would it go to standard output? What in the code specifies that it should go to standard output? Standard output is a specific destination, it's not a default.

Comment: Why does it go to the standard output for cout?

Comment: @jrok ostream_withassign is a derivative of ostream class

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't compile because `ostream`s default constructor is protected. You need to have a `streambuf` ready to pass it to constructor.

Comment: @user - `ostream_withassign` is an old class that didn't make it into the C++ standard.

Comment: You cannot create a new stream that goes to the standard output because you already have one. Operating two streams that go to the same place usually makes little sense and can easily lead to trouble. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 11):

Stream objects require a buffer to send data to the external device. The standard output stream object, `std::cout`, is initialized with a buffer the encapsulates transport to wherever your output appears. Here is a contrived example:

```
std::ostream cout(/* buffer */);
```

To make your own stream object that pretends to be the standard stream object, you can simply pass the buffer of `std::cout` to its constructor. Note that I wouldn't recommend doing this in practice:

```
std::ostream copy(std::cout.rdbuf()); // Note: not a *real* copy

copy << "Hello World";
```

Comment: so cool!For me, it's like a fresh trick.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set the ostream object(what does this stream output to), of course you can't use it. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/ostream/
i.e.

```
// ostream constructor
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  filebuf fb;
  fb.open ("test.txt",ios::out);
  ostream os(&fb);
  os << "Test sentence\n";
  fb.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can we make this code to send output to the standard output just like cout does?

Comment: @user - We can't without using some OS specific knowledge. That's why we already have `cout` in the standard library.

Comment: @user1232138 You could derive from `ostream` and pass `cout`s `rdbuf()` as ostream's constructor parameter. I'm not sure if that's a good idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

**ostream** class is derived from **ios** class.
Constructor of ios class looks like below.

```
public: explicit ios (streambuf* sb);
protected: ios();
```

Which means default constructor of ios is protected and hence you can't create object using default constructor of ostream.

Only way left to create object of ostream is using *streambuf* sb* argument.

```
std::ostream my_obj(std::cout.rdbuf());
```

Similarly, you can't pass ostream objects by value.

**Reason**

ios is derived from ios_base.
Its copy constructor is private.

```
protected: ios_base();    
private: ios_base (const ios_base&);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this only:

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& gvar = std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;

int main() {}
```

from:
http://xazax.web.elte.hu/